# Organizing Scala implicits associated with a type

Tags: scala, implicit, circe, quill.io

I'd like to introduce some types to represent possible values of a field in a larger type. This fields needs to be possible to encode/decode to/from JSON and also be able to be written/read to a database.

I'm still new to Scala and the type I would like is the sum type `Status = NotVerified | Correct | Wrong`. Since I want to have a string representation associated with each constructor, I created a sealed case class with a `String` parameter and then objects extending that case class. In order to be able to encode/decode, I also need to have implicits, but I'm not sure how to structure this. I could put them in a new object inside the object, like this:

```
sealed case class Status(name: String)
object Status {
  object NotVerified extends Status("not_verified")
  object Correct extends Status("correct")
  object Wrong extends Status("wrong")

  object implicits {
    implicit val encodeStatusJson: Encoder[Status] =
      _.name.asJson
    implicit val decodeStatusJson: Decoder[Status] =
      Decoder.decodeString.map(Status(_))

    implicit val encodeStatus: MappedEncoding[Status, String] =
      MappedEncoding[Status, String](_.name)

    implicit val decodeStatus: MappedEncoding[String, Status] =
      MappedEncoding[String, Status](Status(_))
  }
}
```

… and then explicitly `import` these where needed, but that's quite … explicit.

What is a good way of organizing such collections of a type + implicits?

Comment: The way you have implemented `Status` is problematic because you can create `Status("not_verified")` but the type will be `Status` rather than `NotVerified`, and a `match` on type will not give the right results. You can make `Status` `abstract` but I suspect that this will break the `Decoder`.

Comment: @Tim Oh. You're right! Thanks! I don't _really_ want subtypes here. I guess I should use a sealed trait and then case classes extending that? But then the decoders/encoders quill/circe wants will be very repetetive…

Comment: Yes, that is the right way to do a simple enumeration. Make `Status` abstract and create a companion object `Status` with `def apply(name: String): Status = ...` which matches the string and returns the appropriate subclass. Then `Status("not_verified")` will return the right underlying type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common approach is to define a `sealed trait`:

```
sealed trait Status {
  def name: String
}

object Status {
  case object NotVerified extends Status {
    val name = "not_verified"
  }
  case object Correct extends Status {
    val name = "correct"
  }
  case object Wrong extends Status {
    val name = "wrong"
  }
}
```

Or a `sealed abstract class`, which may look nicer in the current Scala versions:

```
sealed abstract class Status(val name: String)

object Status {
  case object NotVerified extends Status("not_verified")
  case object Correct extends Status("correct")
  case object Wrong extends Status("wrong")
}
```

To avoid the need to import implicits, they can be placed directly in the companion object of the type. See also the question [Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits) for more details, especially the section *Companion Objects of a Type*.

And yes, defining implicits for enumerations like that easily gets repetitive. You have to resort to reflection or macros. I recommend using the [Enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum) library, which also has integrations with Circe and Quill.
Here is an example for Circe:

```
import enumeratum.values._

sealed abstract class Status(val value: String) extends StringEnumEntry {
  def name: String = value
}

object Status extends StringEnum[Status] with StringCirceEnum[Status] {
  val values = findValues

  case object NotVerified extends Status("not_verified")
  case object Correct extends Status("correct")
  case object Wrong extends Status("wrong")
}
```

And you can use it without defining any encoders/decoders explicitly or importing anything from `Status`:

```
scala> import io.circe.syntax._

scala> val status: Status = Status.Correct
status: Status = Correct

scala> status.asJson
res1: io.circe.Json = "correct"

scala> Decoder[Status].decodeJson(Json.fromString("correct"))
res2: io.circe.Decoder.Result[Status] = Right(Correct)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add an `apply` method you can create the appropriate `Status` from a `String`, which should make the `Decoder` work properly. And making `Status` abstract

```
sealed abstract class Status(name: String)

object Status {
  object NotVerified extends Status("not_verified")
  object Correct extends Status("correct")
  object Wrong extends Status("wrong")

  def apply(name: String): Status = name match {
    case "not_verified" => NotVerified
    case "correct" => Correct
    case _ => Wrong
  }
}
```

I think your existing implicits will still work, but I don't know those specific libraries...